# KDE 4.7 - Plasma Netbook - Change the top panel to autohide

Tags: kde, panel, settings, plasma-netbook

Does anyone know how to set the top panel in Plasma Netbook **not** to autohide?

I am aware this can easily be done with Plasma Desktop (by clicking the "cashew" and then "more settings").

However it appears the same option is not available under Plasma Netbook.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to find a way through the GUI to change this, but editing the `~/.kde4/share/config/plasma-netbookrc` file and changing the `panelAutoHide` value to **false**, then logging out and back in worked for me.